# "Merged Terms" triggers pop-up "There was an error processing the request"

Tags: 2013, error, managed-metadata, term, merge

I have documents tagged with terms using a managed metadata column.
I can tag all the documents without issue.

However, when I update a document **some** of the terms produce a pop-up "There was an error processing the request". Most terms do not have this pop-up.

I looked at the ULS Logs and cannot find a correlation with the error.

Has anyone experienced this? If so, did you find a solution to this issue?

---

**UPDATE January 19**

"Merged Terms" triggers pop-up "There was an error processing the request" when editing properties.

I still have not solved the issue of no pop-ups.
Has anyone experienced this?